# ng-init value is not showing

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to learn the basics on angular. I installed angular via npm.

Just trying to run my first app

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>ngClassifieds</title>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="ngClassifieds" ng-init="message = 'Hello' ">

        <h1>{{message}}</h1>

        <script type="text/javascript" scr="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="scripts/app.js"></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

In my app.js it's just this line of code:

```
 angular.module("ngClassifieds", []);
```

I ran the below command to start up the server as I had installed http server on my project directory

```
 http-server
```

I opened up my localhost url which was localhost:8080 but for some reasons it was not showing Hello message but instead it was showing {{message}}

Not sure what I went wrong here.

Comment: check your developer console for errors

Comment: already check it. No errors are showing up @EbinManuval

Comment: actually the code is working fine. checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/z0uc0nas/

Comment: any idea why on my chrome it doesn't work? I tried all the link provided in the terminal and recheck it but it's still showing {{message}}

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

it is not `scr` chenge it to `src`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below code will solve you problem.

```js
angular.module("ngClassifieds", []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>ngClassifieds</title>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="ngClassifieds" ng-init="message = 'Hello' ">

        <h1>{{message}}</h1>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: we can initialize scope variable without controllers.